# S3 PutBucketWebsite AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I would like to create a pure redirect bucket in AWS S3, I am sure the s3client is operational without problems.

```
$subdomain = 'test.example.com';
$redirectURL = 'https://www.somedomain.com/redirect?someparam';
$bucketID = $s3->createBucket(['Bucket' => $bucket ]);
$arg = array(
                'Bucket' => $bucket, // REQUIRED
                'WebsiteConfiguration' => array( // REQUIRED
                    'ErrorDocument' => array( 'Key' => 'err.html', ),
                    'IndexDocument' => array( 'Suffix' => 'index.html', ),
                    'RedirectAllRequestsTo' => array('HostName' => $redirectURL, ),
                    'RoutingRules' => array(
                                        array(                                        
                                            'Redirect' => array(
                                                'HostName' => $redirectURL,
                                                'HttpRedirectCode' => '301',
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                ),
            );
$result = $s3->putBucketWebsite($arg);
```

However, it output following error even i tried to change some other settings.

```
> Request ID E00C517E4F812581 
Error Type client 
Error Code MalformedXML
```

I wonder if there's any hidden setting I need to add on it.

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectAllRequestsTo` is mutually exclusive with `ErrorDocument`, `IndexDocument`, and `RoutingRules`.  If you are redirecting everything elsewhere, there would be no evaluation of the error or index documents, nor would the routing rules be applicable.

> **RedirectAllRequestsTo**
>
> Describes the redirect behavior for every request to this bucket's website endpoint. If this element is present, no other siblings are allowed.
>
> Type: Container
>
> Ancestors: WebsiteConfiguration
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTwebsite.html

Comment: $arg = array(
                'Bucket' => $bucket, // REQUIRED
                'WebsiteConfiguration' => array( 
                    'RedirectAllRequestsTo' => array('HostName' => $redirectURL, ),
                ),
            );
$result = $s3->putBucketWebsite($arg);

Comment: however i changed the above things, it's still MalformedXML

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the solution by this, it works

```
$subdomain = 'test.example.com';
$protocol = 'https';
$redirectURL = 'www.somedomain.com/redirect?someparam';
$bucketID = $s3->createBucket(['Bucket' => $bucket ]);
$arg = array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket, 
    'WebsiteConfiguration' => array( 
        'RedirectAllRequestsTo' => array('HostName' => $redirectURL, 'Protocol'=>$protocol),            
    ),
);
$result = $s3->putBucketWebsite($arg);
```